# Linq to SQL Where clause returns records that do not match, only when "Edit Top 200 Rows" is used in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql, ssms

I'm having issues wording this question, as the title will probably show you, and for that I apologize.

First, here's a [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj1qg.png) of the issue. That `If` clause there was an attempt at fixing this, but it didn't help.

Every 500ms, the program will run this code to find work that needs to be done. If there is work, it acts on it, changes the status, then `dc.SubmitChanges()`. This works perfectly as is.

If, however, I open up the table in SSMS by using "Edit Top 200 Rows", there is a chance that the connection sometimes breaks, and the `.Where()` will keep returning the same records, over and over, and will not change them. This leads to the program constantly doing the same work. I can't find any errors being returned, anywhere.

Code to follow:

```vb
Private Function EstablishConnection() As Boolean
    Try
        'test connection
        If dc.tblCycleControls.Count() <= 0 Then

        End If
        Return True
    Catch
        'didn't work, make connection!
        Try
            dc = New dcDataContext(Settings.Settings("ConnectionStr"))
            dc.Connection.Open()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Logger.Log("Database connection failed" & vbTab & ex.Message.ToString(), Logger.LogType.StatusLog)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Try
End Function

Private Function PrintLabels(ByVal state As Object)
    'Prevent timer from firing while we're still processing
    timerPrintLabels.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)

    Dim addLabelCallBack As New addLabelCB(AddressOf addToLabelsBox)

    If EstablishConnection() Then
        For Each printQueue In dc.tblCyclePrintQueues.Where(Function(q) q.Status = 0).OrderBy(Function(q) q.CreateDate)
            'Fix for if "Edit top 200 rows" is used in SSMS
            If printQueue.Status = 0 Then
                'Show that we picked it up
                printQueue.Status = 1
                Me.Invoke(addLabelCallBack, New Object() {DateTime.Now.ToString("G") & vbTab & printQueue.AutoSeq})

                'snip

                If System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then

                    'snip

                    'Complete it
                    printQueue.Status = 2
                Else
                    'snip
                End If
            End If

            Try
                If dc.GetChangeSet.Updates.Count > 0 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Changes - " & dc.GetChangeSet.Updates.Count)
                    dc.SubmitChanges()
                    Console.WriteLine("Changes - " & dc.GetChangeSet.Updates.Count)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
            End Try

        Next
    End If

    'Reset timer
    timerPrintLabels.Change(500, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Got it resolved, though not sure if it's the right way. I was holding a reference to my connection (the `dc` object), and re-using it where possible thinking it'd save overhead. That used some kind of caching, it seems. Instead, i've implemented the disposable approach with using blocks, and now it works flawless.